# Lightning component from Managed package not available on record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package

**Update 3**

Issue is still there even for non dynamic components. If someone can provide me tips and tricks.

---

I have three components in my package:

`A` is a component used in `app toolbar`. It works and is also available on `app builder`(useless).

```
<aura:component description="A"
                access="global"
                implements="force:appHostable,
                            flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
</aura:component>
```

- AppHostable was required for packaging (else error).
- AvailableForAllPageTypes was required for toolbar.

---

`B` is a component used on `record page` level. It is **not** available in `package components`.

```
<aura:component description="B" 
                            implements="force:hasRecordId,
                            flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
                            flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
                            force:hasSObjectName"
                access="global"
                controller="BCtrl"
>
</aura:component>
```

- AvailableForRecordHome was required for record page.
- AvailableForAllPageTypes has been added for test purpose but is not required

---

`C` is a component used on `record page` level. It is **not** available in `package components`.

```
<aura:component description="C"
                implements="force:hasRecordId,
                flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
                flexipage:AvailableForAllPageTypes "
                controller="CCtrl">
</aura:component>
```

- AvailableForRecordHome was required for record page.
- AvailableForAllPageTypes has been added for test purpose but is not required

Everything works perfectly on the dev/packaging org where it is from.

---

**UPDATE**

- Yes, `myDomain` is created and enabled
- Give `access="global"` to every component: does not change anything

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a real tree of dependencies for one of the component:

```
<!-- The only component displayed on the Record page Account/Contact/Lead -->
<aura:component description="A" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" 
                access="global">

  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:ComponentB"     type="COMPONENT" />
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:ComponentC"     type="COMPONENT" />
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:ComponentD"     type="COMPONENT" />
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:ComponentE"     type="COMPONENT" />
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:ComponentF"     type="COMPONENT" />
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:ComponentG"     type="COMPONENT" />

  <c:ComponentB generateDynamic="ComponentC" />
  <c:ComponentB generateDynamic="ComponentD" />
  <c:ComponentB generateDynamic="ComponentE" />
  <c:ComponentB generateDynamic="ComponentF" />
  <c:ComponentB generateDynamic="ComponentG" />

</aura:component >

<aura:component description="B" access="global">

{! v.body }

<!-- JS Create dynamic component from attribute "generateDynamic" -->

</aura:component >
```

`A` is still not available in `App Builder`.

Answer (score 2):

When you include a component, other dependencies are automatically added to your package. Verify that "B" and "C" are already in the package by checking the component list. Please note that components not marked global can't be used outside of your package, so you may need to change the access level accordingly.

Comment: Hey.

Every dependant component is included in package and every component is `access="global"` but it still does not work.

Comment: Does the org you are installing it in have MyDomain enabled?

Comment: Yes of course, else other components wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the package namespace instead of the default namespace when referencing the components in your update 2 example?  Try changing every use of `c:` to `<package namespace>:`.  According to the documentation, using the default namespace inside a managed package is not fully supported yet:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespace_using_package.htm

Comment: I'd give that the namespace a try, too. Also not sure, if component A needs force:hasRecordId to appear for a record home page.

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp This is not for appearing but for behaviour of the component.

Comment: Yes it is already done (namespace)